# Cant get the nodeValue of element

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domxpath

I'm working on a simple seo app that get the rank result from other site thru `curl_multi_getcontent`.

My problem is I can't locate the position of the element using xpath.

```
<div class="mt10">
    <ul class="ResultListWrap">
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead clearfix"></li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix">
            <div class="w25-0"></div>
            <div class="w8-0"></div>
            <div class="w8-0"></div>
            <div class="w8-0"></div>
            <div class="w8-0">
                <a href="">Text</a> <!-- GET THE VALUE OF THIS -->
            </div>
            <div class="w8-0"></div>
            <div class="w25-0"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix"></li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix"></li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix"></li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix"></li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix"></li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix"></li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix"></li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix"></li>
        <li class="ReListCent RelistHead bor-b1s clearfix"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I only need to get the result from the fifth `div` of second `<li>`.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
        $urlContent = curl_multi_getcontent($url);

        $document = new \DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

        // set error level
        $internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        // load HTML
        $document->loadHTML($urlContent);
        // Restore error level
        libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);

        $finder = new DomXPath($document);
        $results = $finder->query('(//div[@class="ReListCent"])[2]/div[5]/a') -> nodeValue;

        if(isset($results)){

          echo $results;

        }else{
          // NO RESULT
        }
```

Comment: Don't include code as image. Always include it as text in a _code section_. This is essential in creating a [mcve].

Comment: @zx485 ok sorry about that..

Comment: looking on the markup, there's no `//div[@class="ReListCent"]` only `//li[@class="ReListCent"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath is incorrect. The elements are `<li>`, not `<div>`, and because the `class` of the `<li>` includes other values, you can't compare it directly. Try this instead:

```
((//li[contains(@class,"ReListCent")])[2]/div)[5]/a
```

Also, [`DOMXPath::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), so to access an individual element you need to specify an index into the list, either using `[n]` notation or `->item(n)`. So you should use:

```
$result = $finder->query('((//li[contains(@class,"ReListCent")])[2]/div)[5]/a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

I've made a small demo showing the basics of the code working on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ei3sN).

Comment: thank you sir, for helping.. `Notice: Trying to get property 'nodeValue' of non-object` I got this message..

Comment: @user123 what happens if you `print_r($finder->query('((//li[contains(@class,"ReListCent")])[2]/div)[5]/a'));`?

Comment: `DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 ) DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 ) DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 ) DOMNodeList Object ( [length] => 0 )`

Comment: That means the XPath is not matching. Are you sure that these elements actually exist in the HTML response you are getting from CURL?

Comment: @user123 I've added a small demo of the code working. I'm thinking perhaps the contents of your page are actually loaded via JavaScript..